# Unity's Application.logMessageReceived missing messages on Android

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

Originally my issue was HockeyApp not reporting on Android (works fine on iOS). Now I'm finding my Application.logMessageReceived callback isn't being called most of the time.

In editor, I'll see the same error in both the Console and my Application.logMessageReceived callback. Yet, on Android I see everything reported in logcat (mostly under I/Unity), yet my Application.logMessageReceived callback seems to be ignoring errors.

Any ideas with where I should dig next? Is there some way to listen everything logcat gets?

Thanks for your time,
Kyle M

Comment: I don't know a proper solution, but you should try [`Application.logMessageReceivedThreaded`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Application-logMessageReceivedThreaded.html), maybe it'll work.

Comment: Hi Maxim,

I replacing logMessageReceived with logMessageReceivedThreaded and it gives the same result. System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException doesn't fire in this case, probably because Unity is catching it?

Still seeing the error in logcat.

Comment: Have you managed to find an answer to this? I'm debugging my exception handling with DivideByZero "bugs" and in Editor it fires the event, but in build it doesn't. It's logged as an error in both cases. If I just throw a generic System.Exception, it's fired at both platforms. Why not DivideByZero exception?

Comment: Sorry Tudvari but it's been 6 years and 3 companies since then. I think we ended up either going with a different solution or changing something with the build pipeline.